# How to have a database with a custom file extension which automatically opens with and only with my java program when file is double clicked

Tags: java, database, windows, swing, file-format

I'm creating a management software which saves all data using a database management system. I will like to know how to get my database have a custom file format like doc for Ms Word, psd for Adobe Photoshop, ai for Adobe Illustrator and when the file is double clicked it automatically opens my java program and loads its data into it.
Can you recommend a DBMS or what do ever which can enable me to achieve this in java?

I'm currently working with sqlite and java swing and to thinking to dive into H2 and JavaFx for future programs

Comment: In Windows, you [associate the extension with the application](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-specific-application-in-windows-10-2/).  For Uniz and macOS, I assume there's an equivalent process.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! I tried H2 and file association and it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will be better if you post your answer in detail here for others who are facing similar situation. Your answer will be helpful for the community.